# Contar período de determinado dia com mais veículos

Tags: c

Estou a realizar um projeto na qual se baseia na criação de uma estrutura, um vetor de uma estrutura, preencher esse vetor com dados de um ficheiro e depois realizar umas funções.

Uma das funções é contar o período de determinado dia com mais veículos. O que tenho de errado e porque?

```
typedef struct _hora
{
  int hora;
  int minuto;
}Hora;
typedef struct _data
{
  int dia;
  int mes;
  int ano;
}Data;
typedef struct _passagem
{
  char matricula[9];
  Data data;
  Hora hora;
  char tipo_passagem[3];
  int portao;
}Passagem;

int hora_maisveiculos(Passagem *v,int x)//4.c 
{
  int dia,i,tamanho=4;
  Passagem *aux;
  aux = (Passagem*)malloc(tamanho * sizeof(Passagem));
  if (aux == NULL) {printf("Erro:Atribuicao de Memoria Dinamica");free(aux);exit(-2);}
  printf("Qual o dia que deseja pesquisar?\n");
  scanf("%d",&dia);
  for (i =0;i<x;i++)
  {
    if (v[i].data.dia == dia)
    {
      tamanho++;
      aux = (Passagem*)realloc(aux,tamanho*sizeof(Passagem));
      aux[tamanho-1]=v[i];
    }
  }
  int menor = aux[0].hora.hora;
  int maior = aux[tamanho-1].hora.hora;
  //for (i = 0; i<tamanho;i++)
  //{
    /*if (strcmp(aux[i].tipo_passagem,"in") == 0)
    {
      if (aux[i].hora < menor)
      {
    menor = aux[i].hora;
      }
      if (aux[i].hora > maior)
      {
    maior = aux[i].hora;
      }

    }*/
  //}

  printf("Maior %d Menor %d \n",maior,menor);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Por que `tamanho` começa em `4`? Assim você nunca atribui valor a `aux[0]`.

Comment: O código é muito extenso? Poderias colocar o código inteiro, assim seria possível o teste diretamente com o compilador.

Comment: Você não disse qual o erro que recebe... Falha na execução (mensagem de erro), retorno de valores errados (quais seriam correctos)? Podes [edit] tua pergunta livremente para adicionar informações.

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com o titulo do post, deves precisar dum array para ter a contagem por periodo. Cada elemento do array corresponde a um periodo.

Por exemplo, se o periodo for 1 hora

```
int contaperiodo[24];
//foreach (passagem) {
//    contaperiodo[passagem.hora] += 1;
//}
/* agora pesquisa no array contaperiodo[] qual o periodo com mais passagens
```